# Making User Calendars visible for all users

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

I'm new to PowerShell. We are an Azure AD cloud tenant and use Exchange online.

I have been using `Set-MailboxFolderPermission` command to make the user's Calendars visible for all other users.

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity John.doe:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails
```

However I now need to do this for multiple users in the organization. So I tried this code, but it fails to run:

```
#Connect-ExchangeOnline 

#importing the CSV source which has the changes 
$data = Import-Csv C:\Temp\userslist.csv

#Iterating through each row in the CSV
foreach ($row in $data)
{
   Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity '$row.username':\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mcg take a look here https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1972546-exchange-powershell-script-for-bulk-calendar-permissions